# Create a stored procedure which accepts list of datatime as a parameter

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using SQL Server localdb ，EF to have a test.

I want to send a name, an id and some datetime to a stored procedure to filter my tables.

Could I create a stored procedure which accepts `List<DateTime>` as a parameter? How to call it from C#?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudents]
    @id int = 0,
    @name varchar(50),
    @date  //date here accepts list of datetime?
```

Comment: To pass the equivalent of a list to a stored procedure you need a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). Read the docs, have a go, and post when you get stuck.

Comment: There are loads of resources out there which show how this is called from C#.

Comment: @Dale K Thanks,Actually, I call the store procedure from asp.net mvc using EF, I want to pass list of dateTime as one parameter into the sp, then filter the database using the `@date`...Is it possible?

Comment: Google is your friend - loads of hits out there on EF using TVP.

Answer (score -1):

Use this field and varchar(max) and then pass a comma delimited string to your procedure.

If you require a list/table again in sql server then you can write split function..

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-and-convert-Comma-Separated-Delimited-String-to-Table-in-SQL-Server.aspx